# Jedis SpringBoot cannot serialize and deserialize Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, redis, jedis

I got following error after adding @Cacheable annotation to one of my rest method:

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.util.ArrayList and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')",
```

Method declaration is:

```
@Cacheable("loadDevicesFloors")
@GetMapping("/floors/all-devices")
public Map<String, DevicesFloorDTO> loadDevicesFloors() {...
```

and DevicesFloorDTO looks as follows:

```
public class DevicesFloorDTO implements Serializable {
    private final List<DeviceDTO> deviceDTOs;
    private final String floorName;
    private final Integer floorIndex;
    public DevicesFloorDTO(List<DeviceDTO> devicesDtos, String floorName, Integer floorIndex) {
        this.deviceDTOs = devicesDtos;
        this.floorName = floorName;
        this.floorIndex = floorIndex;
    }...
```

Additionally my @Bean redisTemplate method implementation:

```
@Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConFactory
                = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedisConFactory.setHostName(redisHost);
        jedisConFactory.setPort(redisPort);
        jedisConFactory.setPassword(redisPassword);
        return jedisConFactory;
    }

@Bean
    public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
```

Does anyone know what is wrong in this implementation? Without @Cacheable it works as expected, but after adding @Cacheable error occurs. I was searching a lot and still don't know what causes this error and how to fix this. Any comment may be helpful. Thaks a lot!

Comment: Can you get the value out of redis with this command: `redis-cli GET '<key>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Generics you have specified for the Map `Map<String, DevicesFloorDTO>` will not be available at runtime during serialization/deserialization.  What format are you trying to save your objects to in Reids? Are they saving as JSON (string) or binary?

We have had success with the `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` because it will save the class info inside the JSON string so Redis know exactly how to recreate objects.

There are also some instances where a Wrapper Object is needed in order to correctly serialize/deserialize objects.

```
    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager cacheManager( RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory,
                                           ResourceLoader resourceLoader ) {
        RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder builder = RedisCacheManager
                .builder( redisConnectionFactory )
                .cacheDefaults( determineConfiguration() );
        List<String> cacheNames = this.cacheProperties.getCacheNames();
        if ( !cacheNames.isEmpty() ) {
            builder.initialCacheNames( new LinkedHashSet<>( cacheNames ) );
        }
        return builder.build();
    }

    private RedisCacheConfiguration determineConfiguration() {
        if ( this.redisCacheConfiguration != null ) {
            return this.redisCacheConfiguration;
        }
        CacheProperties.Redis redisProperties = this.cacheProperties.getRedis();
        RedisCacheConfiguration config = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                .modulesToInstall( new SimpleModule().addSerializer( new NullValueSerializer( null ) ) )
                .failOnEmptyBeans( false )
                .build();
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping( ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY );

        GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer serializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer( mapper );

        //get the mapper b/c they registered some internal modules
        config = config.serializeValuesWith( RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer( serializer ) );

        if ( redisProperties.getTimeToLive() != null ) {
            config = config.entryTtl( redisProperties.getTimeToLive() );
        }
        if ( redisProperties.getKeyPrefix() != null ) {
            config = config.prefixKeysWith( redisProperties.getKeyPrefix() );
        }
        if ( !redisProperties.isCacheNullValues() ) {
            config = config.disableCachingNullValues();
        }
        if ( !redisProperties.isUseKeyPrefix() ) {
            config = config.disableKeyPrefix();
            config = config.computePrefixWith( cacheName -> cacheName + "::" );
        }
        return config;
    }
```

Comment: Chris Savory your answer hits the point. It works! Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of time!